# Angular Pseudo-Clicking a tab using another button

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, tabs

I'm building an Angular app that has three pages accessed by clicking on the tab for each page. These tabs have a ngClick directive used with a custom built "tabs" directive which allows for this functionality.

```
template:
    '<div class="tabbable">' +
      '<ul class="nav nav-tabs">' +
        '<li ng-repeat="pane in panes" ng-class="{active:pane.selected}" id="tab_{{$index}}" class="tab">'+
          '<a href="" id="{{pane.title2}}" ng-hide="pane.selected" ng-click="select(pane, $index)"></a>' +
          '<a href="" id="{{pane.title2}}" ng-show="pane.selected" ng-click="select(pane, $index)"><img ng-src="images/tab{{$index + 1}}_active.png"></a>' +
        '</li>' +
      '</ul>' +
      '<div class="tab-content" ng-transclude></div>' +
    '</div>'
```

In addition to the select() function built for this purpose, I have a couple of additional buttons in my code which are designed to jump to the next tab in the app. To do this, right now I'm using jQuery to pseudo-click the next tab after the current active tab.

```
function nextTab() {
    var children = jQuery(this).children();
    var firstChild = jQuery(children[0]).attr('type');

    jQuery('.tab.active').next().children()[0].click();
}
```

This works, however, I would much rather do this the "Angular Way" and not integrate 3rd part code into my functionality. I've tried creating a function on $scope and applying it via a ngClick directive:

```
$scope.nextTab = function() {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            var children = jQuery(this).children();
            var firstChild = jQuery(children[0]).attr('type');

            jQuery('.tab.active').next().children()[0].click();
        });
    };
```

Unfortunately, this returns an "inprogress: apply" error whenever I try to execute it.

I know that this error is in relation to Angular trying to call $apply on an element that already has the same directive on it (jQuery's click(); against ngClick). What I don't know is how to get around this issue.

Could someone explain how I could achieve the functionality I want through Angular?

**Edit:**
For reference, I've provided the directive's I'm using.

```
module
.directive('tabs', function() {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  transclude: true,
  scope: {},
  controller: function($scope, $element) {
    var panes = $scope.panes = [];

    $scope.select = function(pane, index) {
      angular.forEach(panes, function(pane) {
        pane.selected = false;
      });
      pane.selected = true;

      tabClick(index);
    }

    this.addPane = function(pane) {
      if (panes.length == 0) $scope.select(pane);
      panes.push(pane);
    }

    function tabClick(tabNumber) {
      var tabs = [event_track_brand( 'non-relevant' ), 
                  event_track_brand( 'non-relevant' ),
                  event_track_brand( 'non-relevant' )
                 ];

      tabs[tabNumber];
    }        
  },
  template:
    '<div class="tabbable">' +
      '<ul class="nav nav-tabs">' +
        '<li ng-repeat="pane in panes" ng-class="{active:pane.selected}" id="tab_{{$index}}" class="tab">'+
          '<a href="" id="{{pane.title2}}" ng-hide="pane.selected" ng-click="select(pane, $index)"></a>' +
          '<a href="" id="{{pane.title2}}" ng-show="pane.selected" ng-click="select(pane, $index)"><img ng-src="images/tab{{$index + 1}}_active.png"></a>' +
        '</li>' +
      '</ul>' +
      '<div class="tab-content" ng-transclude></div>' +
    '</div>',
  replace: true
  };
})

.directive('pane', function() {
return {
  require: '^tabs',
  restrict: 'E',
  transclude: true,
  scope: { title1: '@', title2: '@' },
  link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {
    tabsCtrl.addPane(scope);
  },
  template:
    '<div class="tab-pane" ng-class="{active: selected}" ng-transclude>' +
    '</div>',
  replace: true
  };
});
```

This basically is building on the tab/panes directives used on Angular's homepage. Ideally, I'd like to add a function available on the pane directive like this:

```
 scope.nextTab = function() {
      var nextPaneIndex = tabsCtrl.panes.indexOf(scope) + 1;
      var nextPane = tabsCtrl.panes[nextPaneIndex];

      tabsCtrl.select(nextPane, nextPaneIndex);

    };
```

But I can't seem to get something like this to work, or even be accessed within the pane scope. I'm still having trouble fulling understanding how directives work so if someone could explain how to get this work I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: If you haven't changed anything of the `$scope` inside the `$scope.nextTab()`, just do not use the `$scope.$apply()` as it is unnecessary.

Comment: Fair enough, I thought it was considered a best practice to use $scope.$apply() when using third party code like jQuery but if its not needed its not needed. I've tried using this code with and without $scope.$apply() and either way it doesn't work though. Any idea how I can tackle this issue?

Comment: The easiest is the wrap your `nextTab()` code inside a `$timeout`. But it would be better to change tab directly via `$scope`, that would eliminate the use of jQuery.

Comment: Tried using $timeout, which does take care of the "inprogress: apply" error but then doesn't execute the function.

If I could change the tab directly via $scope then this wouldn't be an issue. However, the $scope of the two tabs are not in the same scope and thus can't be accessed that way.

Comment: Hmm, could you show what you have tried? BTW, if it really doesn't work, I would still prefer using `$broadcase/$emit` and `$on` over a fake click event.

Comment: Updated with relevant code and what I would like to accomplish.